# What kind of tree is this with light bark, small leaves, and purple flowers?

Tags: identification, trees

I'd like to buy a tree like this one.  Any idea what it's called?

This picture was taken near Boise, Idaho, USA near the end of July.

[image]

Comment: Erm.... any chance to get close-ups or at least a few more details? We do have some helpful advice on how to ask a good id question in the [tag:identification] tag’s [tag info](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). Please [edit] your post with more details so that the community can help you better.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks. I'm sorry about the picture quality.  That's the only photo I have.  I updated the question with the location and time of year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We really need a clearer, closer image of the flowers and especially the foliage, but on current showing, it would appear to be an Hibiscus, possibly Hibiscus syriacus 'Woodbridge' or similar. With the current image, it's difficult to be certain of that, but that's my best guess https://www.gardendesign.com/flowers/rose-of-sharon.html

When and where this picture was taken is also quite important to know - the Hibiscus I've mentioned flowers relatively late in summer, but there are other Hibiscus which flower earlier, particularly in warmer regions. Otherwise, tree/shrub mallows (Lavatera x clementii for instance) look not dissimilar once large, and they have similar flowers, but flower from early summer onwards - that's another (but rather less likely) possibility for ID.

Comment: The "rose of Sharon" that I've seen in the UK (and have in my own garden) looks more like a shrub (growing to about 2 meters tall) than a tree with a trunk.

Comment: @alephzero Yea, they look like that for years, fairly slow growing, but mature ones do form a trunk, though its usually necessary to remove lower limbs to expose it. The answer's just a guess anyway, without seeing better photos - if  this photo has been taken from the web or a book, the OP may not have any more photos to upload either.

Comment: I updated the question with the location and time of year (near Boise, ID, USA at the end of July).  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: It doesn't, really - I'd expect the Hibiscus I mention to start flowering in July. We really need a close up of leaves and flowers, but I'm guessing its got no flowers and has dropped its leaves at this time of year.

Comment: Great guess!  I was able to contact the property owner.  It's a rose of Sharon.